# how to use a value with white spaces within a select for datatables in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datatable with name field and can have names(firstname surname)with white spaces between two words.

when I use a `select` method to query the records, I get nothing in return

example:

```
  DataRow[] results = datatable.Select("Name = 'FITUR DISPELOR'");
  Console.WriteLine(results.Count().ToString());
```

gives me 0 count of returned results.

But if I write the following, I have a matching record.

```
DataRow[] results = datatable.Select("Name = ''");
Console.WriteLine(results.Count().ToString());
```

Can someone help me out how can I query the full name in a data table? I am using c# for this.

Comment: What is the class for `refinedExcelData`?

Comment: Whitespace should not cause a problem, have you changed the CaseSensitive property of the table?  To ensure the white space is a regular `' '` look at the value of that cell by row/col index & ensure the space is character code 32 `(var hover_me_in_the_debugger = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(table.Rows[y][x].ToString());`

Comment: Like Alex K. said. Check this. 
Generally I would suggest you to use a sequence of LINQ instructions instead a string as expression if not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I used Linq expressions and it has solved my problem.